# How do I move my IPhone backup from one machine to another?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I used to sync my IPhone to my Macbook air using ITunes. All my Apps and other stuff like music and podcast were fully backed up there.

Recently I bought a new mac mini and now I want to create a full backup of my Iphone there. However after, authorizing and fully syncing I noticed that only recently installed Apps were showing up.

How can I get a full backup on the Mac Mini like how I used to have in my Macbook air ?

P/S - I do not backup my Apps on ICloud.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find device backups in ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/

**To locate a specific backup:**

1. Go to iTunes > Preferences.
2. Click Devices.
3. Control-click the backup you want and select Show in Finder.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215

---

**How to back up your devices using iCloud or iTunes**

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977